# Sanity check for Laplace-Stiletjes transform of compound process

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables, laplace-transform, moment-generating-functions, queueing-theory

I have a counting process $Y(t)=\sum_{i=1}^{N(t)}X_i$, where $X_1,X_2,\ldots$ are iid, and $N(t)$ is a non-negative integer random variable independent of $X_i$. I want to calculate the Laplace-Stieltjes transform $\mathcal L$ of $P(N(t) \geq n)$ and want to check the following reasoning. I know the MGF $M_{Y(t)}(s)=\mathcal G_{N(t)}(M_{X_1}(s))$, where $G_{N(t)}$ is the probability generating function and $M_{X_1}(s)$ is the MGF of $X_1$, and I'm trying to use the property [here](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1002/9781118625651.app3) that states <sup>1</sup>:
$$
s\mathcal{L}\{F_X(x)\}=M_X(-s), \text{ for distribution function } F_X.
$$

Can I then claim:

\begin{align}
\mathcal L\{P(Y(t)\geq n)\}(s)
&=\mathcal L\{1-F_{Y(t)}(n)\}(s)\\
&=\frac{1}{s}-\mathcal L\{F_{Y(t)}(n)\}(s)\\
&=\frac{1}{s}-\frac{1}{s}\mathcal G_{N(t)}\left(M_{X_1}(-s)\right)?
\end{align}

---

##### Footnotes

1. From the appendix of the book *Fundamentals of Queueing Theory*
   by John F. Shortle, James M. Thompson, Donald Gross, Carl M. Harris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After thinking this over, I believe the error arises from a simple and obvious mistake, namely $F_{Y(t)}(n)\neq P(Y(t)<n)$. More specifically in my above argument,

$$
\begin{align}
\mathcal L\{P(Y(t)\geq n)\}(s)
&=\mathcal L\{1-P(Y(t)<n)\}(s)\\
&\color{red}{\neq}\frac{1}{s}-\mathcal L\{F_{Y(t)}(n)\}(s)\\
&=\frac{1}{s}-\frac{1}{s}\mathcal G_{N(t)}\left(M_{X_1}(-s)\right).
\end{align}
$$